# socket read issue in multithreaded JAVA application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

We have created a socket in a multithreaded JAVA application on Windows, which has to read data in sequential form. But we are facing issue in reading the data from the inputstream

For example , data order is

```
1-100 (1,2,3,4,...100)
101-200
201-200
and so on..
```

We are able  to read from 1-100 in proper sequential manner, but not able to read next set of data, i.e. 101-200. But can read further set of data properly.

The data is coming at our end properly (as seen in etheral log's), but stream is not able to read it.

Here is the code snippet

```
socket.getInputStream.read(buffer);
```

socket is of Socket class type.

What can be the possible reason behind the same? Please share your views.

Comment: I suspect you're going to need to post a bit more code than that...

Comment: multithreaded - does this mean, more then one thread is sitting on the socket?

Comment: Why do people capitalise Java, I wonder..? Anyway, we need more code from you.

Comment: @Chris Dennett: I blame the caffeine.

Comment: @Chris: [Why do so many people write JAVA instead of Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/why-do-so-many-people-write-java-instead-of-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the code snippet

```
> socket.getInputStream.read(buffer);
```

No it isn't. That snippet doesn't compile. And the correct snippet is trivially obvious.

The only ways that can miss data are (i) if another thread is reading the socket at the same time, or (ii) if you are using BufferedInputStream or BufferedReader at one time and not at another.

Answer (score 0):

You mention this is a multithreaded application so without seeing your code my suspicions would lie in another thread possibly manipulating your Socket or InputStream.  Threading issues can be incredibly difficult to spot and debug.

Comment: I think it's likely that multiple threads are trying to read "different" parts of the input stream at the same time.

Comment: @Harry, Yes I should have been more clear, by reading bytes from an InputStream you change the read position of the stream thus read operations do manipulate the InputStream where peek operations do not.

Comment: There are no 'peek operations' on an InputStream. I don't see the point of this reponse. Read operations consume the input, so it's gone. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. The issue was with multithreading synchronization, i handled the same and it worked fine.